# Regex custom matched tag ang get its group?

Tags: regex, regex-group

I'm trying to create custom markup. This markup will look like this; If there is no attribute then it will be `<mark text mark>` and the group of this match will be text. If this markup has an attribute `<mark:attribute text mark>` will be like this. After the `<mark`, there will be a colon without a space, and an attribute will come without a space. Two groups will be formed from this match, the first group will be the attribute value after the colon, the second group will be text.

### Example

- `<mark text mark>` must match
- `<mark:attribute text mark>` must match

```
<mark
text
mark>
```

must match

```
<mark:attribute
text
mark>
```

must match

---

- `<marktextmark>` should not match
- `<mark>` should not match
- `<mark:attributetextmark>` should not match
- `<mark:attribute textmark>` should not match
- `<mark: text mark>` should not match

---

- `<mark:red ...blah...blah... mark>` must match. First group is **red**, Second group is **...blah...blah...**
- `<mark Lorem Ipsum mark>` must match. The group is **Lorem Ipsum**

*I think it can make matching difficult when mark is capitalized `<MARK TEXT MARK>`. It doesn't matter if it doesn't affect the situation.*

### Summary

- Must start with `<mark`
- If there is an attribute, it should be written with a colon without spaces. `<mark:attribute`
- Must end with `mark>`
- There should be spaces before and after the text. `<mark:attribute text mark>` `<mark text mark>`
- Must have only one group without attribute `<mark text mark>` Group: **text**
- Must have two group with attribute `<mark:attribute text mark>` Group[0]: **attribute**, Group[1]: **text**
- There should be no spaces after the colon, so the attribute value should not be empty.
- And multi-line support.

I tried to write some regex (`<mark:([^*].+?)mark>`) but I couldn't get any result. I hope I was able to explain. https://regex101.com/r/jNsM88/1

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `<mark(?::(\S+))? (.*?) mark>` [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/7C0yI0/1) --- Group 1 is the attribute, null if there is no attribute, group 2 is the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group 0 is always the *entire* match, so captured groups start at 1: Your targets will be captured in groups 1 and 2 (not 0 and 1 as you desire).

Use an optional (ie quantifier `?`) non-capturing group (`(?:...)`) for the attribute and capture non-whitespace `\S`:

```
<mark(?::(\S+))?\s+(\S+)\s+mark>
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/qhnk54K3aQuBPy).

Comment: There is only one missing case here, it does not match when multi line.

Comment: Maybe you should add that to your list of examples...

Comment: Actually, I added it in the summary, but I didn't write it as an example, it would be better if I added it.  However, the work you have done is quite successful, I have been trying for two days and I could not get a result.

Comment: Changed the spacing to just "whitespace", which includes newlines

Comment: Thank you so much.  It provides exactly what I want.